# CreatingLoadBalancerFailed - failed to create target pool / googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for: None is not a valid value, invalid

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to expose a service with Google Container Engine using the following command:

kubectl expose rc image-server --create-external-load-balancer=true

This fails to create the load balancer with the following output from 'kubectl describe services':

"Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to create load balancer for service default/image-server: failed to create target pool a06ecdc229dce11e5a90f42010af0004: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for: None is not a valid value, invalid"

Does anyone know why it's failing to create the target pool and/or what the "Invalid value for: None is not a valid value, invalid" error message might be referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: The incident is over and creating external load balancers should again work as expected.

---

This is caused by https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/15065.

The incident status also links to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/cjcullen/2aad7d51b76b190e2193) that shows the workarounds when using a service yaml file or `kubectl expose`.

Comment: I think this is probably the right answer as I retried the exact same command this morning and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

So it seems like it's a Kubernetes issue ([related GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18347)) of which they are aware, the problem has been fixed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/18365/files)

Apparently the work around is adding the following, in your load balancer service's config until the fix makes it into a release:

`sessionAffinity: "ClientIP"`

Edit: Tried this out and can confirm it works